# Using a 'Where' filter in Jekyll to only return items that are not blank

Tags: jekyll, where-clause, assign

I have a CSV data file that contains a list of projects. I would like to assign variables to filtered segments of the data - then loop through them.

Here I have tried to filter all projects to show only the projects that have been assigned a value in the `global_priority` field. If the project has no value I do not what it in the list.

I have tried using `where_exp`, but it returns everything. What is the best way to approach this? Is it possible to achieve this without using an `if` statement?

**projects.csv**

```
name,global_priority,region,region_priority
Project A,1,Global,
Project B,,Spain,1
Project C,2,UK,1
```

**The loop**

```
{% assign projects = site.data.projects %}
{% assign global_p = projects | where_exp: "item.global_priority", "item.global_priority != blank" %}

  {% for p in global_p %}
    <ul>
      <li>{{ p.global_priority }}</li>
      <li>{{ p.region }}</li>
      <li>{{ p.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small mistake in the way you access the `where_exp` item, it should refer to the name you will use in the comparation: `where_exp: "item"`

Then:

```
{% assign global_p = site.data.projects | where_exp: "item", "item.global_priority" %}

{% for p in global_p %}
<ul>
  <li>{{ p.global_priority }}</li>
  <li>{{ p.region }}</li>
  <li>{{ p.name }}</li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Outputs:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>Global</li>
  <li>Project A</li>
  </ul>

<ul>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>UK</li>
  <li>Project C</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I see that now - much appreciated!